# Why Xcode12.5 has no iOS14.6SDK

Tags: ios, ios14, xcode12.5

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYaSr.png)

The Document shows that 'The iOS & iPadOS 14.6 SDK provides support to develop apps for iPhone, iPad, and iPod touch devices running iOS & iPadOS 14.6. The SDK comes bundled with Xcode 12.5', but I cant find it.

Comment: The document is wrong. The release notes for Xcode are right: "Xcode 12.5 includes SDKs for iOS 14.5".

Answer (score 1):

Xcode 12.5 App Store update note doesn't contain any reference to iOS 14.6.

[image: update note from app store]

Also see the [Xcode 12.5 release note](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/Xcode-Release-Notes/xcode-12_5-release-notes)

May be the next release will support iOS 14.6.

( Answering because comment doesn't support image)

Comment: Thanks! But the ios14.6 Release Notes says 'The SDK comes bundled with Xcode 12.5', so i'm confused. maybe it's a mistake? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/ios-ipados-release-notes/ios-ipados-14_6-release-notes

Comment: May be, or Xcode will have a minor update soon.

Comment: I would guess because 14.6 is more like a patch release. I'm not seeing any changes to the SDK APIs, so the 14.5 SDK may be compatible and an explicit 14.6 SDK may not exist. If this is the case certainly the language on the 14.6 release notes is misleading. Unusual, though, as I don't recollect a minor release ever not be accompanied with an Xcode update.